# Manage values of one process from another in runtime

Tags: java, android, android-activity, runtime

I want to manage values of one application from another in runtime, but don't understand the basic principle, algorithm how to do this.

What I have tried:

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();

try {
    intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mypackage");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Some error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This code starts LAUNCH activity of another application in current task. It works fine, but after next activity is starts - previous activity is paused and I haven't any tools to control child activity. My task is to obtain values of child activity from parent activity in runtime and have ability to change this values also in runtime, not just send intents from one activity to another with startActivity() method.
I know about System.getenv() and Runtime.getRuntime().exec() and think that it's that I need, but I can't combine it into whole project to achieve my goal. Device is rooted.

Will be very grateful for the help.

Comment: does your both app have database?

Comment: no, values should be taken from memory in runtime